# when compiling No static field DEF_CONTENT_CHARSET of type Ljava/nio/charset/Charset; in class Lorg/apache/http/protocol/HTTP;

Tags: java, android, android-studio, httpclient, vonage

when using the nexmo api version 3.0+ (not using 4.0+ because require android version 8 api 27 ) and android version 6 api 23

i cannot send sms, as it is always giving the aforementioned error: No static field DEF_CONTENT_CHARSET of type Ljava/nio/charset/Charset; in class Lorg/apache/http/protocol/HTTP;

send sms code:

```
    AuthMethod auth = new TokenAuthMethod(APIKey, APISecret);
    NexmoClient client = new NexmoClient(auth);

    TextMessage message = new TextMessage(fromRecipient, toRecipient, messageContent);

    SmsSubmissionResult[] response = client.getSmsClient().submitMessage(message);

    for (SmsSubmissionResult responseMessage : response) {
        System.out.println(responseMessage);
    }
```

I imported the following:

```
implementation 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.5+'

implementation 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:4.4+'
```

but it is still looking at the legacy httpclient instead of the imported ones

is there a way to force use the imported http client/core libraries instead of the legacy library?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're trying to use the Nexmo Java Server SDK with Android. This is not something that is supported because it would require storing something like secrets and private keys inside of your application.

The recommended approach is to use the Server SDK on a server somewhere to secure this information, and then use your own authentication scheme to communicate with it via the Android app.